# Bad url after a sign up HTML, Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem. I implemented a signup and a login page. I have the correct url (localhost:3000/login and localhost:3000/signup). But I have a problem. I enter in the signup and I insert the data of the user then if you press the button you are redirecting to localhost:3000/login but I have this error:

Cannot GET /login?firstname=a&lastname=a&username=a&email=a%40e.i&password=a&repeatPassword=a

In practice, when I press the button, all the data that the user has inserted are also added to the url. How is it possible? Can you help me please? Here is my code:

SIGNUP.DUST

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Signup</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/standardize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
<script src="js/library.js"></script>
<script src="js/model.js"></script>
<script src="js/utils.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="body signup">
  <div class="vertical-align-wrapper">
    <div class="vertical-align-box">
      <h1 class="slogan">Now listen.</h1>
       <div class="form-signup-wrapper">
         <form action="/login" method="GET" class="form-signup">
           <input class="form-control form-stacked" name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname" type="text" required="true" id="Firstname">
           <input class="form-control form-stacked" name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname" type="text" required="true">
           <input class="form-control form-stacked" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" required="true" id="username">
           <input class="form-control form-stacked" name="email" placeholder="email" type="email" required="true">
           <input class="form-control form-stacked" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" required="true" >
           <input class="form-control form-stacked last" name="repeatPassword" id="repeat" placeholder="Repeat password" type="password" onkeyup="enable()" required="true">
           <input class="btn btn-beats btn-block btn-stacked" value="Sign up" id = "btnPlaceOrder" type="submit" onclick="setuplogin()">
        </form>
        <p>Already have an account? <a href="login" class="beats"><strong>login</strong></a> now!</p>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1 class="fat blue-glow bottom-right">Atelier<span class="pulse" style="display:inline-block;">Beats.</span></h1>
```

LOGIN.DUST

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/standardize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/dust-core.min.js"></script>
<script src="/views/views.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="body login">
  <div class="vertical-align-wrapper">
    <div class="vertical-align-box">
      <h1 class="slogan">Gotta <i class="fa fa-heart beats pulse" style="color:#B13A3D;"></i> that sound.</h1>
  <div class="form-login-wrapper">
     <form action="library.html" class="form-login">
     <input class="form-control form-stacked" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" required="true" id="username">
     <input class="form-control form-stacked last" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" required="true" id="password" onkeyup="validation()">
     <input class="btn btn-beats btn-block btn-stacked" value="Tune in" type="submit" id="submit">
     </form>
     <p>Don't have an account? <a href="signup" class="beats"><strong>sign up</strong></a> now!   </p>
   </div> 
 </div>
</div>
<h1 class="fat blue-glow bottom-right">Atelier<span class="pulse" style="display:inline-block;">Beats.</span></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

APP.JS (where are all my function that I'm using)

```
function setuplogin(){
    var userName = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var data = {
        userName : userName,
        password : password
    };
    console.log(data);
    doJSONRequest("POST", "/users/", null, data, function(){
        document.location = location.location;
    });
}

function validation(){
    var userName_login = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password_login = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var data = {
        userName : userName_login,
        password : password_login
    };
    doJSONRequest("GET", "/users/", {}, data, function(location){
        document.location = location.location;
    })
}

 function enable(){
     var a = document.getElementById("repeat");
     var password = document.getElementById("password");
     var repeat = document.getElementById("repeat");
          document.getElementById("btnPlaceOrder").disabled = password.value !== repeat.value;
 }

 function timeout(){
       window.setTimeout(function(){
             window.location.href = "../../login.html";
       }, 600000);
 }
```

And finally the doJSONRequest. This function is in another document but it's function works. I inserted all the function you should needs to be sure. Hope I explained my problem in the right way:

```
 function doJSONRequest(method, url, headers, data, callback){
 if(arguments.length != 5) {
     throw new Error('Illegal argument count');
 }
 doRequestChecks(method, true, data);
 var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
 r.open(method, url, true);
 doRequestSetHeaders(r, method, headers);
 r.onreadystatechange = function () {
       if (r.readyState != 4 || (r.status != 200 && r.status != 201 && r.status != 204)){
          return;
       }else{
           if(isJSON(r.responseText))
              callback(JSON.parse(r.responseText));
           else
              callback();
       }
 };
 var dataToSend = null;
 if (!("undefined" == typeof data) && !(data === null))
     dataToSend = JSON.stringify(data);
     r.send(dataToSend);
 }
```

Thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you have any event listeners for your form submission?

If that is the case, then you have your form method set to `GET` which will pass the request parameters in the url.

Change the form method to `POST` and the details will go in the request body, rather than as url paramerters:

```html
<form action="/login" method="POST" class="form-signup">
```

Comment: Where does that error come from? It sounds like your page isn't configured to handle a POST request?

Comment: Then, if from the signup page I press the login link I have "Cannot GET /login"